# What is the "base" of a git diff?

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

The XY question that I want to ask but suspect is not fully on topic is "How can I remember/memorise the various syntaxes of git diff?" The git diff syntaxes are (personally) confusing, and it's not clear to me how you can remember what they do *intuitively* (i.e. without rote memorisation), because the underlying logic doesn't seem clear.

But to break down the question further, my issue in clarity is this: what is the default *base* of a git diff?

Here is my understanding of the git diff syntaxes so far:

- `git diff`: compares working directory with staging area
- `git diff HEAD`: compares working directory with HEAD (current commit)
- `git diff branch/commit`: as above, compares WD with branch/commit
- `git diff --staged`: compares staging area with HEAD (?!)
- `git diff foo bar`: compare foo and bar

The most "intuitive" and easy to understand syntax is `git diff foo bar`, or diffing a commit-ish. If "foo" is the "base" of the diff, then "bar" is the "comparison". The rest are not intuitive to me. For example I would have thought `git diff --staged` shows the difference between the working directory and the staging area, but that's not the case.

If I were to re-write these syntaxes using a `file1 file2` syntax, I *think* it would look something like this:

- `git diff` -> `git diff WD..index`
- `git diff HEAD` -> `git diff WD..HEAD`
- `git diff commit/branch` -> `git diff WD..commit/branch`
- `git diff --staged` -> `git diff index..HEAD`

So my hypothesis is this: the base of a `git diff` is the working directory, always. Unless you specify `--staged` or `--cached`, the base changes to the staging area.

The question is:

- Is this a correct interpretation of the logic behind the git diff syntax, and the "base" of the git diff?
- Is there another more **intuitive** way to understand the logic behind the `git diff` syntax, rather than just memorising the commands?

Comment: Alright, as my plea has been edited out I'll comment it here: I please ask users to comment if you leave a close vote and give critical feedback. It's **so** discouraging asking questions on here that I think are on-topic, focused and clear but getting anonymous close votes without feedback telling me what I can do to improve. I will happily action commented feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've written is basically correct, but your `..` syntax is flipped,* and "base" is ambiguous so I'll use the terms "old" and "new". Here is a correct table:

- `git diff <commit1> <commit2>`: general syntax *(<commit1> is "old", <commit2> is "new")*
- `git diff` -> `git diff INDEX WORKTREE`
- `git diff <commit>` -> `git diff <commit> WORKTREE`   *(<commit> can be HEAD, a branch, etc.)*
- `git diff --cached` -> `git diff HEAD INDEX`   *(--staged is a synonym for --cached)*
- `git diff --cached <commit>` -> `git diff <commit> INDEX`

Summary:

- When you specify less than two commits, the default behaviour is to use the worktree as the "new" version. You can specify `--cached` to use the index as the "new" version.
- If you don't specify the "old" version, Git will choose a sensible default (when comparing the worktree, "old" will be the index; when comparing the index, "old" will be HEAD).

One of the reasons for the special cases is that Git's revision syntax can only refer to commits – it can't be used to denote the worktree or the index. So the general syntax (`git diff <commit1> <commit2>`) can't be used to compare the worktree or the index.

The shortest forms (`git diff` and `git diff --cached`) are very convenient when using the following workflow:

1. Make some edits
2. Add them to the index
3. Make some more edits
4. Add them to the index
5. Commit

After steps 1 and 3 (edits), you can use `git diff` to review the most recent edits before you add them to the index. This happens frequently, so it's nice that the command is short to type.

When you are about to reach step 5 (commit), you can use `git diff --cached` to view the changes in the index, which are about to be committed.

The direction can be confusing (e.g. `git diff --cached <commit>` means `git diff <commit> INDEX`, note how the order flipped), but in almost all cases it will be what you want: when you compare the worktree to something, you almost always want to treat the worktree as the "new" version (i.e. *"What edits have I made since <...>?"*), and likewise when you compare the index to something you almost always want to treat the index as the "new" version (i.e. *"What changes are about to go into the next commit?"*). In the rare cases where you want the reverse direction, you can use `git diff -R ...`.

---

*The syntax `git diff <commit1>..<commit2>` is a synonym for `git diff <commit1> <commit2>`, i.e. the order is *old..new*. (Note that `..` has a subtly different meaning outside `git diff`.)

Comment: Ah okay, I think that makes sense! So I had it the wrong way around - a `git diff` with one argument (e.g. `git diff HEAD`) has an implied *second* argument, or what you called the "new" version (`git diff HEAD..WORKTREE`), not an implied first argument. And that second argument is always the worktree unless you specify --cached in which case it's the index. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Also I think this was the lightbulb moment for me: "when you compare the worktree to something, you almost always want to treat the worktree as the "new" version". Understanding that the worktree comes second because you want to see what's changed from the old version (HEAD, commit, branch etc.) to the new version (what's in your working directory) makes sense when you understand the arg syntax as "git diff old new". Thanks again, I think I do get it now!

Answer (score 1):

As [tom answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72869189/1256452), the term *base* isn't that great.  I myself dislike *old-and-new* as well, because you can give `git diff` any arbitrary two commits to compare those, and they can both be "very old".  Well, we could use old and older, perhaps , but what if they're both equally old?  For instance, given the "benzene ring" commit graph fragment:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M--N   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L
```

we can, if we like, diff the snapshots stored in commits `I` and `K`, and they're both equally "old" when compared to the *current* commit `N`.  Or, we can give `git diff` the newer commit first, then the older one: `git diff N G`, and here the "new" commit is `G`, even though it's clearly a lot older.

What I like to go for here is simply "left and right".  We pick one tree-of-files—one commit's snapshot, or whatever—that goes on the left side of the diff, and another tree to go on the right, and Git provides to use a reasonably minimal edit sequence that will *transform* the left-side tree into the right-side tree.

It's worth mentioning, at this point, that we don't have to use two *trees* since we can diff individual files:

```
git diff --no-index -- file1 file2
```

Here `file1` is on the left and `file2` is on the right.  But they're still left and right.  The *really* problematic case is when we have `git diff` produce a *combined* diff, because then we have a single left-side tree and *multiple* right-side trees.

With that out of the way, let me get to what I think is the core of your question, which I'll put in bold here:

> **How can I remember/memorise the various syntaxes of git diff?**

My answer is: **You can't.**  Well, I don't *think* you can.  I have to refer back to the manual pages now and then myself, and I deal with this close to daily!  There *is* a system, but there are lots of exceptions.  Tom's bullet list is excellent, and you can try to memorize the reasoning behind the "flipped when using `--cached`" part, but ultimately, the way to handle this is to keep the documentation close by.

The main thing to remember is that we're always diffing *pairs*.  This is true regardless of whether we're doing trees (then we diff the trees, and pair up files and diff the files) or files (then we just diff the pair of files), and it's even still true when doing combined diffs (where we diff left and right side, repeating the left-side over and over again with a different right-side each time).  Everything in the syntax is about picking the right *pairs*, and the two cases that are special—by *special*, I mean *different from other Git usage*—in `git diff` here are:

```
git diff A..B
```

which is just a semi-deprecated way to spell `git diff A B`, and:

```
git diff A...B
```

which is a request to invoke `git merge-base A B` to find the (singular) *merge base* of `A` and `B` and use that as the left side; the right side here is then always `B`.

In *other* Git usage, `A..B` and `A...B` mean what is documented in [the gitrevisions page](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), which is another manual page to keep close at hand at all times.